# Rstudio: adding exogenous variable for BVAR model

Tags: r, var

I am trying to run BVAR model for library("MSBVAR"). It works fine without exogenous variable (Z= NULL ) but, when I add Z= exogen) I get: **Error in if (num.exog == 0) { : argument is of length zero.**

here is my code:

```
 GDP <- ts(dataIR$RealGDP, start= c(2008, 1), frequency = 12)                  
    CPI <- ts(dataIR$CPI, start= c(2008, 1), frequency = 12)
M3 <- ts(dataIR$M3, start= c(2008, 1), frequency = 12  
 MR <- ts(dataIR$MR, start= c(2008, 1), frequency = 12)
```

#### EXOGENOUS VARIABLE

```
     Rgdp <- ts(dataIR$RGDP, start= c(2008, 1), frequency = 12)#already interpolated
```

All variables are in levels and have same length:

```
        data = cbind(lgdp, lcpi, lm3, dMR)
         names <- colnames(data)
          exogen <- diff(log(Rgdp)
         macro.BVAR <- szbvar(Y=data,
                 p=10, #lag length
                 z=exogen, # exogenous variable
                 lambda0=0.6, lambda1=0.1,
                 lambda3=2, lambda4=0.25, lambda5=0,
                 mu5=0,mu6=0, nu=3, qm=4, # hyperparameters
                 prior=0) #  Normal-Wishart
         summary(macro.BVAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exogen has to be a matrix. Try it with

```
as.matrix(exogen)
```